# What's the meaning of this?

Tags: meaning, sentence, complex-sentences

"The stitches hurt too much not to be tight as a drum"

Comment: The only possible explanation for why the stitches hurt as much as they do must be that they are very "tight". Which I assume implies the stitches are under considerable tension as they hold the edges of a wound together, and this is very painful.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I can't understand whether stitches hurt tight as a drum or it doesn't. The writer says "the stitches hurt" and then he says "too much not to be.." Is he tryna tell that it hurts but not as equally as tight as a drum??

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: It's from a book

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: Another way of parsing is 'the were as tight as a drum because they hurt so much'. Whatever that means.

Comment: The Search by Iris Johansen, the context is needless in this case, I assume, I just need clarification.

Comment: @DirtyBomb: I meant that the construction *[assertion1] **not to be** [assertion2]* means ***assertion2 must be valid** - otherwise it wouldn't be possible for [assertion1] to be valid.* That's to say your writer is asserting that the stitches ***are*** "tight as a drum" (and he's claiming he ***knows*** this to be true, because ***only*** that would explain why they hurt so much).

Comment: "Tight as a drum" is and idiom meaning as tight as the skin on a drum head (the type of drum that one might play in a band).  This is kept tight by various means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a degree of pain which the writer assumes would not be there (i.e. the pain would be less) if the stitches were not as tight as a drum.

The degree of pain is more than that ("too much [not] to"), so the writer concludes that they must indeed be as tight as a drum.

Comment: Hmm I get it, so is the writer tryna say he knows the scope of pain if the stitches were as tight as a drum but as the stitches are much tighter so is the pain? And do you think this type of construction is highly common in spoken English?

Comment: "tryna"? _What is the meaning of this?_

Comment: trying to= tryna

Comment: So why didn't you write 'trying to'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: maybe because this is a chatty website, and "tryna" represented their meaning adequately? (I find it hard to believe that you genuinely didn't understand),.

Comment: Of course I understood.